Search engine for small intranet - Nutch or Manifold?
I'd like to setup a search engine for a small intranet. For this I was looking at Apache Nutch, which could crawl the intranet and store results in Apache Solr. A nice-looking frontent would still have to be found or developed. Then I found Apache Manifold CF, which seems to perform the exact same job.
So now my question: What is the difference between these two? And even more, what would be criterions to decide which to pick?
